# Correct flag to use instead of --icmp-type?

Tags: networking, debian, iptables, raspbian, icmp

I am trying to set up iptables v1.8.7 on a Debian 11 Raspberry Pi to block ICMP timestamp requests and replies. [The tutorial I am following](https://www.putorius.net/mitigate-icmp-timestamp-vulnerabilities.html) and all the other forums I have looked at say to use the flag `--icmp-type`, such as in:

`iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type timestamp-request -j DROP`.

However, when I run this command, I get the error `iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables): unknown option "--icmp-type"`. I can't find an alternative to replace this flag with - all forums use this flag, and the man pages never even mention this flag. I've tried guessing at the proper syntax:

```
pi@fuelightcontrol:/etc $ iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --type timestamp-request -j DROP
iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables): unknown option "--type"
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
pi@fuelightcontrol:/etc $ iptables -I INPUT -p icmp -type timestamp-request -j DROP
iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables): table 'ype' does not exist
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
pi@fuelightcontrol:/etc $ iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 13 -j DROP
iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables): unknown option "--icmp-type"
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
pi@fuelightcontrol:/etc $ iptables -I INPUT -p icmp timestamp-request -j DROP
Bad argument `timestamp-request'
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
pi@fuelightcontrol:/etc $ iptables -I INPUT -p icmp 13 -j DROP
Bad argument `13'
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

Could someone help me find the proper syntax for the command `iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type timestamp-request -j DROP`? Thank you for your time and consideration!

Update: I tried reinstalling iptables using `sudo apt purge iptables` then `sudo apt autoremove` then `sudo apt install iptables`. No success, but now I notice that while iptables-persistent was uninstalled, it was not reinstalled. This should an easy fix if it is needed.

Comment: Does anything change if you add `-m icmp` before this option, and does the file `/usr/lib/*/xtables/libipt_icmp.so` exist?

Comment: I'm not sure where to add `-m icmp`, is this what you meant?


`wllinux@5CG00225WF:~$ iptables -I INPUT -p -m icmp --icmp-type timestamp-request -j DROP`

`iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): unknown protocol "-m" specified`
`Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.`

And yes, that file does exist:

`wllinux@5CG00225WF:~$ find /usr/lib -name libipt_icmp.so -type f -printf "%h/%f\n"`
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xtables/libipt_icmp.so`

Comment: @user1686 Ah, my previous comment's formatting is all messed up, and I couldn't get it to work right in the 5 min edit window. Here's a screenshot of my terminal that shows the same thing: https://imgur.com/a/uQzykli
Basically, I'm not sure where to add -m icmp, is this what you meant? And yes, that file exists.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to add it after the `-p icmp` option, as in `-p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type ...`.

Comment: Also, you're doing this on two different machines, with different iptables versions?

Comment: I just saw that too - No, only one, the pi. I didn't realize I had exited my ssh into the pi. D'oh! `libipt_icmp.so` exists on the pi, and running the command 
`iptables -I INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type timestamp-request -j DROP` gives a "No such file or directory" error. https://imgur.com/a/D9WBwYh

Comment: What happens if you run it as root? Many match types also need a corresponding kernel module.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Nvm, this didn't work. Maybe this will help you though, even though it didn't help me: https://www.unix.com/linux/11290-linux-icmp-timestamp-requests.html

To anyone who finds this in the future: Use nftables instead! What worked for me was this. #'s are comments.

```
nft add table ip filter #create table. I would have needed to enter this, but the table was already created so I didn't have to. 
nft add chain ip filter INPUT { type filter hook input priority 0 \; } # create chain
nft insert rule ip filter INPUT icmp type timestamp-request counter drop
nft insert rule ip filter INPUT icmp type timestamp-reply counter drop
sudo systemctl start nftables
sudo systemctl enable nftables
#backup your old /etc/nftables.conf file first before continuing
sudo nft list ruleset > /etc/nftables.conf
```